# Will LIMIT affect the number of slots that get used?

Tags: google-bigquery

We recently moved to BigQuery's flat-rate billing model. This means we purchase a finite amount of slots and all BigQuery queries in our organisation will make use of those slots.

I am wondering whether or not the number of slots used by a query will get affected by use of `LIMIT`. TO put it another way, will this query:

```sql
select *
from project.dataset.table
```

use more slots than this one?

```sql
select *
from project.dataset.table
limit 10
```

?

Comment: Not an answer, but if your limit query had an `ORDER BY` clause, then BigQuery would still have to sort the entire table.

Comment: Did you run the queries and examine the execution details or the BigQuery data access logs?